# How to solve second degree differential equation?

Tags: python, sympy, ode

For the differential equation `mx'' + kx = 0` (where `x''` is double derivative of `x` with respect to `t`), how to solve this for `x(t)`? I mean how to get this equation:

```
x(t) = c1*cos(sqrt(k/m)*t) + c2*sin(sqrt(k/m)*t)
```

What I tried:

```
t, g, k, m, w0, a_0, b_0, c1, c2 = symbols('t g k m w0 a_0 b_0 c1 c2')
x = symbols('x', cls=Function)
w0 = sqrt(k/m)
diffeq = Eq(x(t).diff(t, t) + k*x, 0)
```

but the statement `diffeq = Eq(x(t).diff(t, t) + k*x, 0)` throws an error:

```
TypeError: unbound method as_base_exp() must be called with x instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: Have you tried the [first example of `dsolve()`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/ode.html#dsolve)?

Comment: @kennytm; I edited the question.

Comment: @kennytm; OK, I got it wrong. I figured it out how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work and able to solve the equation for coefficients `C1` and `C2`. Here is the code:

```
t, a0, b0, k, m, g = symbols('t a0 b0 k m g')
x = Function('f')
diffeq = m*Derivative(x(t), t, t) + k*x(t) + m*g
# print(diffeq)
x_sl30 = dsolve(diffeq, x(t)).rhs
print(x_sl30)

# Initial condition, x(0) = a0 and x'(0) = b0
c_0 = Eq(x_sl30.subs(t, 0), a0)
c_1 = Eq(x_sl30.diff(t).subs(t, 0), b0)
# print(c_0)
# print(c_1)
C1, C2 = symbols("C1, C2")
C1C2_sl = solve([c_0, c_1], (C1, C2))
#Substitute the value of C1 and C2 in the original equation
x_sl31 = x_sl30.subs(C1C2_sl)
print(x_sl31)
```